# Web push notifications not showing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, notifications

currently I am developing web push notification service for our project. The problem I am facing is that my service worker in Google Chrome receives push signal, but won't show it as notification, although I am able to log data to dev console. I tried it on Firefox and also on Chrome in another devices and it does work. I tried to restore chrome settings, but it's not helping. Here is my service worker code:

```
'use strict';

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

var payloadJson = JSON.parse(event.data.text());

const title = payloadJson.title;
const options = {
    body: payloadJson.message,
    icon: 'img/img.png',
    badge: 'img/img2.png'
};

event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

After push service worker logs messages as expected:
[Dev tools console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkLvX.png)

As I mentioned I tested it on chrome with another device which had Chrome v64 meanwhile mines is v65.0.3325.162 Both of devices runs on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3

EDIT: 
So i found some strange behaviour, after completely deleting chrome with all cached files and reinstalling it I was able to make it work, but now the issue is, that if I wait till notification will dissaper it will not be shown next time. Everything works until I click close on notification.

Comment: Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that if the `options` argument for the `showNotification()` is invalid, i.e. the file(s) specified in either the `icon` or `image` field don't exist, then the method call silently resolves without raising an error or anything. This is probably why you see the `push` event coming in yet not seeing the notification itself. I'm not sure about the connection with the behavior you explained after reinstalling the service worker, though.

Answer (score -1):

To send a notification, the payload must use the [`notification` key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message_payload):

```
var payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'My Title',
        body : 'TEST'
    }
};
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47379794/2292766